# XCode upgraded to 4.4.1 and now I get errors compiling in stl <vector>

Tags: c++, xcode

Upgraded to XCode 4.4.1 and restarted my machine, recompiled and now get the error below when I try to compile - any suggestions? (It used to compile fine)
(Running on Lion 10.7.4, XCode Version 4.4.1)

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H

#include <vector> <-- this line
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include "assert.h"

using namespace std;
```

Error message

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector:69:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:69:1: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NESTED_NAMESPACE(std, _GLIBCXX_STD)
```

Comment: You file is a .h file ? Xcode may try to compile it as C not C++

Comment: I don't think so - it's included from a .cpp file

Comment: Are you sure it's the only inclusion / import ? It's the only cause I can see so far :/

Comment: Yah, I suspect it's done a clean build and a problem thats been around for a while has surfaced. Thanks

Comment: Nope just dumbness on my part - I'd cut and pasted some pascal code in by mistake in a header file, it seemed to really upset the compiler though.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem is still actual, I suggest you should check the following project setup lines:

- C++ Language Dialect (mine: Compiler Default)
- C++ Standard Library (mine: Compiler Default)
- Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C (mine: Apple LLVM compiler 4.1)

Not all combinations work and not always the "Compiler Default" is the default. I had some problems, too.

(From the error message it looks for me like you are using libstdc++ instead of libc++ but not the gcc compiler or so. I had similar problem after the update.)